# Reading file from a different project gcloud -file not found error even though the file exists

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to read a `json` file from **project B** in Google cloud using a service account from **project A**. The service account in **project A** is granted `read role` in the **project B**. But when I am trying to open the json file I am getting:

> `"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://x.json'`. The file **x.json** does exist.

I checked the list of privileges (`storage.objects.get ,storage.objects.list`) to read a file from https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from analytics import Clients, ClientType
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
from pytz import timezone
from typing import List
from pyarrow import json as pyj
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import newlinejson as nlj

bigquery_client = Clients.get_client(ClientType.STORAGE, name='w')
write_client = Clients.get_client(ClientType.BIGQUERY, name='w')
k_client = Clients.get_client(ClientType.BIGQUERY, name='w')

bucket ='update'


file_name_prefix = "al_"
target_table = k_client.get_table("w.junk.json_table1")

def get_dates() -> List[str]:
    """
    Return dates for which log files have to be checked
    """
    end = date.fromisoformat(str(datetime.date(datetime.now(timezone("EST")))))
    return [str(end - timedelta(days=1)), str(end)]

def get_bucket_files(bucket, file_name_prefix):
    # if full_path:
    path = "gs://{}/{}"
    #path = "https://storage.googleapis.com/{}/{}"
    return [
        path.format(bucket, b.name)
        for b in bigquery_client.list_blobs(bucket, prefix=file_name_prefix)
    ]

def get_latest_file() -> str:
        """
        Get all files for the current prefix between start and end date
        """
        files = []
        files_json = []

        for d in get_dates():
            prefix = file_name_prefix + d[4:] + "-" + d[:4]

            files += get_bucket_files(bucket, file_name_prefix)
            for k in files:
                filename = k.split('/')[-1]
                if 'json' in filename:
                    files_json.append(k)
            return max(files_json)

def pipeline():
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
#         schema=[
#             bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING")
#         ],
        autodetect=True,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
    )
    f = get_latest_file()
    print(f)
    table = pyj.read_json(f)
    # pq.write_table(target_table, table.parquet)
    # with nlj.open(f) as src:
    #     with nlj.open('out.json', 'w') as dst:
    #         for line in src:
    #                  dst.write(line)
#     k_client.load_table_from_uri(
#         f, target_table, job_config=job_config
#     ).result()


pipeline()
```

Comment: Can you provide your sample code? Based on the error message, it seems to be expecting a path/directory from your local client instead of a google storage URI path.

Comment: I am using the gsutil format and the bucket is created using backstage. Please find sample code. @ScottB - Can you pleas elet me know if its possible to provide a path thats not local or of project B. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider and try the below approach in [listing objects in buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-list-files#storage_list_files-python):

```py
from google.cloud import storage

my_bucket = 'your-bucket-name'
my_prefix = 'al_'

client = storage.Client()

def get_bucket_files(bucket, file_name_prefix):
    for blob in client.list_blobs(bucket, prefix=file_name_prefix):
        print(str(blob))

get_bucket_files(my_bucket, my_prefix)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if the bucket is not local to the project. Only option that works is to download the file to a temp location.

Comment: I was able to use the code when I executed it from `Project A` and then use *Service Account* with *Viewer* role on `Project B` to list objects on a bucket from `Project B`. Can you share your error message?